# How to find the radix used for floating-point numbers without using macro or trial and error

Tags: floating-point, radix

Is there a way to find out the radix being used for floating point numbers other than:

a) reading FLT_RADIX

b) assuming that it's either two or ten and finding it by looking at the output of algorithm generating the largest value that can be represented by the type and checking which one is the highest?

Edit:
Anything else that can be programmed in C/C++ is allowed.

Comment: How about: "Read the documentation of your compiler/interpreter/..."? (Maybe say what should be allowed, instead of trying to list things which you don't want to allow)

Comment: Sure, that's a way, but I've meant an algorithm I can program rather than something I can do myself.

Comment: Use `return std::numeric_limits<T>::radix;` (can be programmed in C++ and does not use the `FLT_RADIX` macro)

Comment: I'm using CPP N-IDE (com.duy.c.cpp.compiler) and it complains that numeric_limits is not a member of std. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In C, `scalbn(1, 1)` produces the radix of the `double` format.